# Terraform apply to Azure - where can I see the list of changes made by running apply against Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm coming from a Bicep/ARM template deployment background.

With ARM templates I can go the portal, select my resource group, and from the Deployments blade I can see the deployments made.

Is there an equivalent "record" of the changes made by running terraform apply? The activity log blade does show some activity but it's a bit difficult to parse out what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. The current state is stored in the terraform.tfstate file but there's no concept of history built in the open source tool. One option is to store the state in a private git repo because the file can contain sensitive information. A second option is to use a backend provider supporting versioning (Blob storage do). Another option is to use Terraform Cloud which keeps history as "runs".

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've got the state in blob storage so I'll look at using versioning.

Comment: Another option would be to run Terraform in Azure DevOps Pipelines (or Github actions etc.) and retain builds that applied changes.